# block timestamp in near-workspace.js

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

Please help me. I am testing near smart contracts using near-workspace.js and ava. I could not find how to get last block timestamp or current block timestamp. And how to move time in near-sandbox. I am testing locally. I tried to find in github of near-workspace.js but it was failed.

Please give advice or share link where i read about it. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.